# How can I get Git to follow symlinks?

Tags: git, symlink

Is my best be going to be a shell script which replaces symlinks with copies, or is there another way of telling Git to follow symlinks?

PS: I know it's not very secure, but I only want to do it in a few specific cases.

Comment: is there a disadvantage to using hard links for something like this?

Comment: With Windows 7, "mklink /d" (directory symbolic link) doesn't work with git, but "mklink /j" (juction) works fine.

Comment: If the file is autogenerated by an application which regenerates it in such a way that it deletes the file and creates  a new one, then yes, this is a problem hardlinks to files won't solve.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury you can't make hard links for directories

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury hard links require the link and the destination to be on the same disk

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury I tried using hard links and ended up having unexpected errors with old files being committed by accident instead of the updated ones. My solution was to write a script to convert the soft links to hard, commit and then revert all the links back to soft again.

Comment: You also can't make hard links when the files are in separate filesystems.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**NOTE:** This advice is now out-dated as per comment since Git 1.6.1. Git used to behave this way, and no longer does.

---

Git by default attempts to store symlinks instead of following them (for compactness, and it's generally what people want).

However, I accidentally managed to get it to add files beyond the symlink when the symlink is a directory.

I.e.:

```
  /foo/
  /foo/baz
  /bar/foo --> /foo
  /bar/foo/baz
```

by doing

```
 git add /bar/foo/baz
```

it appeared to work when I tried it. That behavior was however unwanted by me at the time, so I can't give you information beyond that.

Comment: The commits 725b06050a083474e240a2436121e0a80bb9f175 and 806d13b1ccdbdde4bbdfb96902791c4b7ed125f6 introduced changes that stopped you adding files beyond symlinked directories, so this won't work in versions of git since 1.6.1

Comment: $ git add src/main/path/ConvertSymlinkToDir
fatal: 'src/main/path/ConvertSymlinkToDir' is beyond a symbolic link

Comment: @user1767316 read the whole thing, and the comments. It used to work, it no longer does. Software changes, but stack-overflow accepted answers don't.  I've clarified this doesn't work already. Look at another answer.

Comment: yes @KentFrederic but wiriting the exact error message returned help stack user's search for the solution to its problem.tried to cancel downvote but locked sorry. On the one hand your answer is right given the warning, on the other hand one should give priority to answer working now rather than in the past

Comment: Commit [e0d201b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0d201b61601e17e24ed00cc3d16e8e25ca68596) makes it seem like the git maintainers really don't want symbolic links to be resolved. I don't understand why, but I suppose I'll resort to using a bind mount.

Answer (score 182):

What I did to add to get the files within a symlink into Git (I didn't use a symlink but):

```
sudo mount --bind SOURCEDIRECTORY TARGETDIRECTORY
```

Do this command in the Git-managed directory. `TARGETDIRECTORY` has to be created before the `SOURCEDIRECTORY` is mounted into it.

It works fine on Linux, but not on OS X! That trick helped me with Subversion too. I use it to include files from an Dropbox account, where a webdesigner does his/her stuff.

If you want to make this bind permanent add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/sourcedir /targetdir none bind
```

Comment: Would be a very nice approach if sudo wasnt required.

Comment: To undo this binding, use `umount [mydir]`. (+1 for your great tip, @user252400)

Comment: sshfs can achieve that kind of trick without requiring the sudo, here.

Comment: @sylvainulg: sweet trick! you still need sudo but only to install sshfs [apt-get install sshfs]. Then a simple [sshfs username@localhost:/etc/folder ./target_folder] does the job for git. Brillant ;). Best solution here for me!

Comment: What is/are the difference(s) between this and a hard link?

Comment: For OSX, use http://bindfs.org/ (you can get it with `brew install bindfs`, be sure to follow the instructions displayed on screen to properly setup osxfuse).

Comment: This plays nice with etckeeper. Maintain all you system wide configuration in /etc!

Comment: Really nice trick. @WiseOldDuck one possible difference it's really sucks makes `hardlink` for directories. With this we can use hardlinks for files and `mount --bind` for directories.

Comment: Can you run git commands from inside the mount point?  For me it thinks I'm outside of the repo.

Comment: If you put it in /etc/fstab with `bind,user` instead of just `bind`, it'll be set up so you can mount and unmount without sudo as needed.  That's potentially useful to have that if you're going to be making changes which require the bind mount to be temporarily disconnected.  Stick a `,noauto` on there to not have it bound at boot, too.

Comment: You can use `bwrap` to bind mount directories without `sudo`, It's available on all major distributions and likely comes preinstalled on many. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645471/10126273) bellow for more details.

Answer (score 90):

Why not create symlinks the other way around? Meaning instead of linking from the Git repository to the application directory, just link the other way around.

For example, let’s say I am setting up an application installed in `~/application` that needs a configuration file `config.conf`:

- I add `config.conf` to my Git repository, for example, at `~/repos/application/config.conf`.
- Then I create a symlink from `~/application` by running  `ln -s ~/repos/application/config.conf`.

This approach might not always work, but it worked well for me so far.

Comment: Seems to be the only way, and its not that bad... i think yours is quite an elegant approach. git tracks content, not files. So keeping all content together and symlinking from there to other places makes sense

Comment: In my case I wanted a link from one git repo to another, so I can edit files in either location and commit back to their respective remotes. On Windows 7, a junction ("mklink /j") did the trick.

Comment: of course. sometimes the answer is just that simple.

Comment: what if you want to git both the source AND the destination? (because both belong to different codes you want to have in different repositories)

Comment: other way arouind there is an nginx that is refusing serve files from symlink

Comment: Because if you want to share a folder between two git repositories then you can't do it 'the other way around'. I honestly think git needs to incorporate a --follow-symlinks option.

Comment: I was looking to backup my profiles from various applications and I feel like that's the best approach, you could also add to your repository a script that creates these links back (in my case it's what I needed).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question :( I wanted part of my repository being synced into my iCloud. Unfortunatelly, iCloud doesn't follow symlinks, so I thought I may make git follow symlinks, and store original files in iCloud. Turns out nobody follows symlinks :\

Answer (score 65):

Use hard links instead. This differs from a soft (symbolic) link. All programs, including `git` will treat the file as a regular file. Note that the contents can be modified by changing *either* the source or the destination.

## On macOS (before 10.13 High Sierra)

If you already have git and Xcode installed, [install hardlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118678/288906). It's a microscopic [tool to create hard links](https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink).

To create the hard link, simply:

```
hln source destination
```

#### macOS High Sierra update

> Does Apple File System support directory hard links?
>
> Directory hard links are not supported by Apple File System. All directory hard links are converted to symbolic links or aliases when you convert from HFS+ to APFS volume formats on macOS.
>
> *From [APFS FAQ on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html)*

Follow https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink/issues/31 for future alternatives.

## On Linux and other Unix flavors

The `ln` command can make hard links:

```
ln source destination
```

## On Windows (Vista, 7, 8, …)

Use [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create a junction on Windows:

```
mklink /j "source" "destination"
```

Comment: This is only for HFS/HFS+ on osX!

Comment: Just a note: this is basically what I was looking for, but then I learned that on Linux, a hardlink unfortunately cannot cross filesystem boundaries (which is my use case).

Comment: This approach won't work if your target has some symlink in its path.

Comment: You can't hardlink to directories, can you?

Comment: `ln source destination` works in OS X, too. Tested on El Capitan.

Comment: @Nanne no, but you can do: `cp -al source destination`. `-l' means hard link files instead of copying.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot hard-link directories, or across file system boundaries. This makes this solution twofold unworkable for me.

Comment: Even @Paolo solution is KO across file systems: cp: cannot create hard link ‘localDirpath1/file’ to ‘/dirpath2/file’: Invalid cross-device link

Comment: Directory hardlinks are not working on APFS with OSX High Sierra.

Comment: Works beautifully on windows

Comment: Does this not break as soon as any operation unlinks either instance of the file (as in one has both copies of the file but the hardlink is broken)? Reverting patches, etc. use unlink.

Comment: @Walf , yes good editors and git itself usually don't simply overwrite _into_ files with `st_nlink > 1`, and at least ask for overwrite vs creating a new file - preferring the new file creation. So using hard links here is like painting on water ...

Comment: I find the given `ln` notation confusing (and the wrong way around?). From the man page: `ln TARGET LINK_NAME`

Comment: Note that this might not be really resilient as the source can change inode easily. For instance, if it is in a git repo, and if you git pull --rebase, it will get a new inode.

Answer (score 30):

This is a [pre-commit hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) which replaces the symlink blobs in the index, with the content of those symlinks.

Put this in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
# (replace "find ." with "find ./<path>" below, to work with only specific paths)

# (these lines are really all one line, on multiple lines for clarity)
# ...find symlinks which do not dereference to directories...
find . -type l -exec test '!' -d {} ';' -print -exec sh -c \
# ...remove the symlink blob, and add the content diff, to the index/cache
    'git rm --cached "$1"; diff -au /dev/null "$1" | git apply --cached -p1 -' \
# ...and call out to "sh".
    "process_links_to_nondir" {} ';'

# the end
```

#### Notes

We use POSIX compliant functionality as much as possible; however, `diff -a` is not POSIX compliant, possibly among other things.

There may be some mistakes/errors in this code, even though it was tested somewhat.

Comment: It's great to see an attempt to actually answer the question for files and not directories.

However, note that the above will still show ``typechange`` in ``git status`` for the files which are actually symlinks though git now things they are not.

Comment: Thanks for this; just wanted to know, what is `process_links_to_nondir`?

Comment: @sdaau It is the name/`argv[0]` which is used as the command-name for the `sh` process. (Took me a bit to figure that out, since I didn't remember what it was either ☺ )

Comment: @Abbafei Can you modify the script to make it work on Ubuntu (14.04)? It is showing `find: missing argument to -exec'`. May be a step by step command execution is needed instead of piping & combining everything into single line.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam For me it worked to remove the commented lines in between the command lines. However, the hook does not work as expected (I get the `typechange` like @DavidFraser, but the linked file seems not to be staged anymore)

Comment: I made a post-commit hook to copy files in git repository to linked folder.

Answer (score 21):

On macOS (I have Mojave/ 10.14, `git` version 2.7.1), use `bindfs`.

`brew install bindfs`

`cd /path/to/git_controlled_dir`

`mkdir local_copy_dir`

`bindfs </full/path/to/source_dir> </full/path/to/local_copy_dir>`

It's been hinted by other comments, but not clearly provided in other answers. Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Comment: seems great for teams that all run on mac os, I think hard links outlined below should work for windows and linux.

Comment: This was helpful, and I think the best solution for a useful-but-missing capability in MacOS.  Note however that I was getting `Failed to resolve`...`No such file or directory` errors *unless* I used **full path names** with the `bindfs` command.

Comment: Thanks @electromaggot . Added clarification that full paths necessary

Comment: Works great on macos Catalina!

Comment: Not working on Big Sur, error: `bindfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!`

Comment: @PrashantShubham , https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/1654#issuecomment-873538291 might help (explicitly `brew install --cask macfuse`)

Comment: @PrashantShubham @ijoseph once you install `macfuse`, you have to download the latest version of `bindfs` and build it. You MUST use `gmake` (the version installed with `brew`) not the Mac default `make` to get it to work. Follow the steps in the `README` to make and install. Once its installed, be sure to create the empty sub-directory first, since this is essentially a mount operation. And as noted, `bindfs` requires a full path on both parameters (and in target be sure to add the directory you created as the mount point as the last element in the path)

Comment: @AronT Weirdly enough, I needed to do this again 4 years later, and had to find this answer to remember how. "You MUST use gmake (the version installed with brew) not the Mac default make to get it to work" was untrue for me; `/usr/bin/make` (`GNU Make 3.81` (Copyright (C) 2006)) worked fine.

Comment: @ijoseph that is indeed strange. Maybe there is something else going on that `gmake` stepped around, which newer version of Mac OS X deal with. Even weirder is that Apple hasn't upgraded its version of `make` nearly 2 years on!

Comment: @AronT ah, that's explained by Apple wanting to DRM its stuff and related aversion to GPL-3: https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/393oqv/why_is_the_version_of_bash_included_in_os_x_so_old/cs03n0r/

Answer (score 20):

I got tired of every solution in here either being outdated or requiring root, so [I made an LD_PRELOAD-based solution](https://github.com/Alcaro/GitBSLR) (Linux only).

It hooks into Git's internals, overriding the 'is this a symlink?' function, allowing symlinks to be treated as their contents. By default, all links to outside the repo are inlined; see the link for details.

Comment: Very creative solution using `LD_PRELOAD` to override library functions!

Comment: Yes, but it ought to be elaborated here. Can you do that?

Comment: Not sure how much elaboration would help; unless I copypaste the entire source code, this answer will always rely on that link, where a readme can also be found. But yes, I guess I could reproduce the important parts of the readme.

Comment: This does not compile on OS X (Mojave 10.14.2). Get four errors complaining about 'strchrnul' (did you mean 'strchr'?) and one about '__xstat64' (did you mean '__lxstat64'?). Finally I get a "member access into incomplete type 'dirent64'" error.

Happens regardless if I use "make", "make OPT=1" or "sh install.sh".

Comment: @ErikVeland I tried a bit, but it seems like OSX does not support LD_PRELOAD, nor anything similar. Various docs suggest various things, but they're all several years old, and Apple loves deprecating stuff; I couldn't get any of them working. Sorry.

Comment: This is really a smart and Niubi solutions. I like it and it works

Answer (score 16):

I used to add files beyond symlinks for quite some time now. This used to work just fine, without making any special arrangements. Since I updated to Git 1.6.1, this does not work any more.

You may be able to switch to Git 1.6.0 to make this work. I hope that a future version of Git will have a flag to `git-add` allowing it to follow symlinks again.

Answer (score 8):

With Git 2.3.2+ (Q1 2015), there is one other case where Git will *not* follow symlink anymore: see [commit e0d201b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0d201b61601e17e24ed00cc3d16e8e25ca68596) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster) (main Git maintainer)

#### `apply`: do not touch a file beyond a symbolic link

> Because Git tracks symbolic links as symbolic links, a path that has a symbolic link in its leading part (e.g. `path/to/dir/file`, where `path/to/dir` is a symbolic link to somewhere else, be it inside or outside the working tree) can never appear in a patch that validly applies, unless the same patch first removes the symbolic link to allow a directory to be created there.
>
> Detect and reject such a patch.
>
> Similarly, when an input creates a symbolic link `path/to/dir` and then creates a file `path/to/dir/file`, we need to flag it as an error without actually creating `path/to/dir` symbolic link in the filesystem.
>
> Instead, for any patch in the input that leaves a path (i.e. a non deletion) in the result, we check all leading paths against the resulting tree that the patch would create by inspecting all the patches in the input and then the target of patch application (either the index or the working tree).
>
> This way, we:
>
> - catch a mischief or a mistake to add a symbolic link `path/to/dir` and a file `path/to/dir/file` at the same time,
> - while allowing a valid patch that removes a symbolic `link path/to/dir` and then adds a file `path/to/dir/file`.

That means, in that case, the error message won't be a generic one like `"%s: patch does not apply"`, but a more specific one:

```
affected file '%s' is beyond a symbolic link
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, `mount --bind` doesn't seem to work on Darwin.

Does anyone have a trick that does?

[edited]

OK, I found the answer on Mac OS X is to make a hardlink. Except that that API is not exposed via `ln`, so you have to use your own tiny program to do this. Here is a link to that program:

*[Creating directory hard links in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432540/creating-directory-hard-links-in-macos-x)*

Enjoy!

Comment: If the destination directory of this hardlink is a subdirectory of another git repo, this would be a chaos. Doing git operations in the hardlink would apply to this other git repo. Just double check what you are doing.

Comment: It's possible to do this via https://code.google.com/p/bindfs/ which can be installed using port.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation of what [@user252400](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079380/10126273) proposes is to use `bwrap`, a small setuid sandbox that can be found in all major distributions - often installed by default. `bwrap` allows you to bind mount directories *without* `sudo` and automatically unbinds them when git or your shell exits.

Assuming your development process isn't too crazy (see bellow), start bash in a private namespace and bind the external directory under the git directory:

```
bwrap --ro-bind / / \
      --bind {GIT-DIR} {GIT-DIR} \
      --bind {EXTERNAL-DIR} {MOUNTPOINT-IN-GIT-DIR} \
      --dev /dev \
      bash
```

Then do everything you'd do normally like `git add`, `git commit`, and so on. When you're done, just exit bash. Clean and simple.

Caveats: To prevent sandbox escapes, `bwrap` is not allowed to execute other setuid binaries. See `man bwrap` for more details.

Comment: @tenders-mcchicken Doesn't work when using git commit. `fatal: Unable to create '/home/pcuser/Documents/Desktop-Projects/localhost/.git/index.lock': Read-only file system`

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Yep because everything but the external directory was mounted as read-only, You can either mount everything as read-write (i.e. `--bind / /`), or you can mount only the git directory as writable (which is what I did in my updated answer). Please note that I may no longer answer or update my answers on this site because of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Git 1.5.4.3 and it's following the passed symlink if it has a trailing slash. E.g.

```
# Adds the symlink itself
$ git add symlink

# Follows symlink and adds the denoted directory's contents
$ git add symlink/
```

Comment: at least on OSX this results in `fatal: 'src/' is beyond a symbolic link`

Comment: As explained by @Mark Longair, this only worked until git 1.6.1

Comment: that was my issue, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from symlinks could be useful. Link in a Git folder instead of a symlink [by a script](http://ryans-bliggity-blog.blogspot.com/2006/10/convert-soft-links-to-hard-links.html).

Comment: care to add more details to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You should use hard links as changes made in the hard links are
staged by git.

**2.** The syntax for creating a hard link is **`ln file1 file2`**.

**3.** Here **file1** is the location of the file whose hard link
you want to create and **file2** is the location of the hard link .

**4.** I hope that helps.

Comment: This might not be really resilient as a file can easily get a new inode. For instance, if your tracked file is in a git repo, then a git pull will change the inode of the file, making both files out of sync.