# Adding a common configuration file to all projects within a solution in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2008. I have added a configuration file (called configuration.xml) to the "Solution Items" of the solution.

The idea is to have this file copied to each Project's debug/release directory upon build.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the post build step for each of your projects add the following line

```
copy /Y $(SolutionDir)/configuration.xml $(ProjectDir)
```

If your configuration file is in a solution subdirectory you have to add that to the source path of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the file as a link to each project (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336525/sharing-code-between-2-projects-without-a-dll/4336560#4336560).) This is often easier to see than looking at the project properties for a post-build step.