# MonoTouch: Default.png file as a Link does not work

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, hyperlink, monodevelop, splash-screen

MonoTouch 5.4, XCode (newest)

We have many apps that share a `common splash screen`. We'd like to have `1 real folder`, then have all the variations of `Default.png` for each and exist as `Links` to that simple folder so as to make editing more efficient.

When we set a `Default.png` file to `Link` and `Content`, we can not see it in the `Project's Properties`. When we move a copy physically to the root of the project, it appears and works.

Is there a way to have Default.png exist as a link in each project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test and using a symlink worked. And [Git handles file synlinks OK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/420175) if you use it for version control.

For example:

```
$ rm Default.png
$ ln -s ../../Common/splash-iPhone.png Default.png
```

When run, Default.png on the simulator was a "real" file.

Comment: Well, you did ask "Is there a way to have Default.png exist as a link in each project?" and my UN*Xy solution should work ;-). I would create a Xamarin feature request via https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=MonoTouch if you want a more MonoDevelop centric solution.