# git add . vs git add -A

Tags: git

I have seen on SO [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042390/git-add-asterisk-vs-git-add-period) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add) saying that there is one difference between git add . vs git add -A, and it's related to deleted files being staged by git add -A and not git add .

But I tried it on git 2.3.2, as far as I can tell, deleted files are staged by both commands.  Has this behavior changed?

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  That post also says that rm operation is not captured by git add .  I read that before posting this as well.

Comment: Have you read past the first answer? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26039014/1984384) one. I think that should cover the differences in behavior between the different git versions. Note, that `git add .` only adds changes from the current directory, whereas `git add -A` also stages changes from the parent dir(s).