# Difference between $ git add --all vs $ git add *?

Tags: git

When I do `$ git add *` sometimes I realized that git doesn't add the deleted files to the stage and I need to indicate manually if remove or add it, but I can't figure out what's the difference with `$ git add --all`.
So if the asterisk (*) indicates 'everything' (*)**, why git doesn't add all like **--all** flag'?

I checked the git documentation [git-add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) and some [Difference between “git add -A” and “git add .”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add) but doesn't specify the case when using asterisk.

Also the first answer in [git add * (asterisk) vs git add . (period)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042390/git-add-asterisk-vs-git-add-period)  indicates:

> add * means add all files in the current directory, except for files, whose name begin with a dot. This is your shell functionality, actually, Git only receives a list of files.

So it means that is identically * and --all?

Thanks

Comment: `*` is expanded by the shell to all the names in the current directory. Git can't care about `*` because it never sees an asterisk, only names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is:

- `git add -A` adds everything [from the *top* git repo folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309).
  It operates on the *entire* working tree, and not just on the current path.
- `git add *` adds the files (as **expanded by the shell**, [without dotfiles](https://stackoverflow.comhttps://stackoverflow.com/q/26042390/6309)) from the *current* folder.
  It operates starting from the current path.