# Git Repository and commit going fine but refuse to upload folder content

Tags: git, ember.js

I am new to git and have obviously read and watch lots of tutorial.

Set up everything with terminal, everything is working very well with bitbucket.

BUT: my ember.js project is not uploading at all. I have a greyout folder in my repository and nothing is commit or push.

Every files i commit or push goes up there no problem but i dont understand why my project folder wont upload.

I have tried so many thing found here or elsewhere on the net, I've even tried to solve this with git client, but still the folder containing my project won't upload.

The last thing I tried : `git init` inside the folder :

```
iMac:new01 nick$ cd red-green-client
iMac:red-green-client nick$ git add *
```

Which produces an error:

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>
> bower_components
>
> dist
>
> node_modules
>
> tmp
>
> Use -f if you really want to add them.

When I try to commit:

```
iMac:red-green-client nick$ git commit -m "third test"
```

I get:

> On branch master
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Push doesn't work as well:

```
iMac:red-green-client nick$ git push
```

> fatal: No configured push destination.

Im out of idea. help ?

Comment: You shouldn't commit `bower_components dist node_modules tmp` directories. It is not a problem, if the only problem is that.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are getting is clearly telling you what the problem is: you are trying to add files that are configured to be ignored in this repository.

### You probably don't want to add the listed folders to your repository.

More on this [here](http://blog.silvabox.com/should-you-commit-bower-components-to-git/).

### Adding files via `*` doesn't make sense in 99% of times when working with git.

More on `git add` behavior with different arguments and flags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26042555/4725998).

Comment: Tanxs for your answer. Indeed the files that are ignore should have been, i should have update the .gitignore first, but that still does not commit or push any of the others files in this folder. I shall keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mistake in having the remote repo with files that are not in the local repo. Like that the console is returning this message telling that files are in the repo and not in the local. In this case, you can pull all the files from the repo to have them in the local as well, so the repo and the local at the same page. Check that and see what can happen.