# Is there a difference between "git add ." and "git add *" with respect to outcome?

Tags: git, git-add

Both seem to add everything in the current directory. The [Git add documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) points to [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec), which points to [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html).

The docs suggests that `git add .` will add everything in the current directory, while `git add *` will add everything that matches `*`, which happens to be everything in the current directory. This then should result in the same outcome right? Perhaps `git add .` is a bit more performant because we don't have to expand the glob first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git add \* (asterisk) vs git add . (period)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042390/git-add-asterisk-vs-git-add-period)

Comment: It possibly helps to reiterate that when you run `git add *` (on a Unix-like system, Mac OS X included), _the shell_ expands the `*` and the `git` programs receives the string "add" as its first argument and the names of the files produced by the shell as the rest of the arguments. The dot, `.` is passed to `git add` literally, and handled by `git add` by itself. The fact `*` as implemented by commonly used shells does not match the so-called "dot files" is actually a "usability hack" from the olden days, and it [can be configured](https://superuser.com/a/373751/130459).

Answer (score 4):

> This then should result in the same outcome right?

Not exactly

Since `*` does not match hidden files in the shell, `git add *` will not add the hidden files/dirs in the current directory (but hidden files in subdirs will match since you add the full dir).

`git add .` will add everything, including hidden files in current dir.

Simple POC to illustrate:

```sh
$ tree -a
.
├── blah
├── .hidden
└── some
    ├── dir
    │   ├── .hidden
    │   └── titi
    ├── .hidden
    └── tata

2 directories, 6 files

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /mydir/.git/

$ git add *

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   blah
    new file:   some/.hidden
    new file:   some/dir/.hidden
    new file:   some/dir/titi
    new file:   some/tata

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .hidden

$ git add .

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .hidden
    new file:   blah
    new file:   some/.hidden
    new file:   some/dir/.hidden
    new file:   some/dir/titi
    new file:   some/tata
```

Comment: I'll be glad to know in which way this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Don't know why the negative votes. Adding hidden files sounds like a big difference to me... just consider .gitignore, .gitattributes.... that's a _big_ difference in outcome.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, but note that some command-line interpreters (the old CMD one on Windows, notoriously) don't expand `*` themselves. In this case it's up to Git to do it.