# How to add a text file to git repository? the file is under visual studio release directory

Tags: git

The file is under Release directory which is the binary file output place.

[image]

The other files would be presented once it was edited. But the text file under release directory doesn't.

I tried to use git bash.

```
git add /d/test/ClipBird/Release/bal.txt
fatal: D:/test/ClipBird/Release/bal.txt: 'D:/test/ClipBird/Release/bal.txt' is outside repository
```

Comment: Maybe try something like this <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072125/git-add-command-is-returning-fatal-outside-repository-error-message</a>

Comment: <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072125/git-add-command-is-returning-fatal-outside-repository-error-message</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either move the file `bal.txt` to some location inside your Git repository folder, or add the binary `Release` folder to Git.  I don't advocate the latter option, because, as you mentioned, this folder mainly contain binary output artifacts which should not be versioned by Git anyway.

You may want to take a step back and think about how `bal.txt` ended up the `Release` folder.  Perhaps you should find a way to write this folder inside the Git repo folder.

Comment: Yes, I see. the [Rr]elease/ was ignored in .gitignore. I have to copy it to other directory.