# What happens when moving a git repository. Is it safe?

Tags: git

Is it safe to move a git repository? (assuming that everyone else updates their `remotes` and `symlinks`)

In the original question, I had noticed that git creates what seemed to be symlinks under `.git/objects`. But I now realize that they aren't symlinks.

Note that this question is different from the one asked at: [How does git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) since I am asking about symlinks **created** by git.

As requested in the comments, here is an example:

```
$ ls -ld ./something.git/objects/7a/f87b48b897fde759daaff2b0a781691d5a625a
-rwxrwxrwx 1 XXX YYY 188 Jan 25 17:12 ./something.git/objects/7a/f87b48b897fde759daaff2b0a781691d5a625a*
```

Comment: I haven't seen this before (symlinks under `.git/objects`) - could you add the output of `ls -ld` for one of these?

Comment: Thanks @MarkLongair I added an example.

Comment: that isn't a symlink - it's a regular file, but with unusual permissions (readable, writable and executable by everyone) - it's probably displayed in an unusual colour by `ls`, which might make it easy to confuse with a symlink.

Comment: `find -L` says to follow symbolic links when walking through the directory structure - did you mean `find PATH -type l`?

Comment: Sorry @MarkLongair you are absolutely right. Your point about permissions and colors made me believe that `find -L` was printing symlinks. I am re-formulating the question to specifically ask about whether or not it is safe to move a git repository, although I guess I already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'move', you mean the command `mv`, then yes, this is safe. Git doesn't make relative path references outside a given repository directory.

Comment: Should note that git itself won't do it to you, but git won't prevent you commiting relative symlinks to your repo or explicitly adding relative urls as remotes or alternates.

Answer (score 1):

in git you can move, rename copy etc without any side effects.

Git store all its information inside the .git folder (inside the root dir) so as long as you dont mess with the .git folder you are safe and can move, copy, rename the folder.