# Git push symbolic link targets. (homesick gem)

Tags: ruby, git, github, symlink

I could only find information about what happens when you push symbolic links to git, but not about when you push their targets.

My problem is that I wanted to have my dot files for vim in Github. So I moved .vim and .vimrc from Ubuntu's home to other directory and created symlinks to them in that directory. Then when I pushed the other directory and opened the github repository in my browser the directory were somehow turned with green icon and it can't be clicked. It looks like this:
[image]

I used the [homesick gem](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick), but it appears that the problem is not from it, because the repository of the maintainer of the gem, with his dot files is okey.(https://github.com/technicalpickles/pickled-vim and he uses the gem too)

My guess is that the problem appears, because the dir is target to a symlink, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I'm new to git, but if i am not wrong, the green icon means submodule, why the directory is considered by github as a submodule? Because it is a target to symlink?

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/955926) for how git stores symlinks. Read through the rest of that post, too. It's about symlinked files and folders.