# Git error: unable to create symlink

Tags: git, gitlab

I have an error that is driving me insane, I can't for the life of me get the latest commits from my repo onto the dev server. How do I get around the unable to create symlink errors? For context I'm ssh into the server and trying to pull the latest commits.

```
$ git pull origin master
From gitlab.com:
* branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating ae388636..
error: unable to create symlink app/code/community/Varien/Profiler.php: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink app/code/community/Zend/Db/Profiler.php: File name too long
```

This also happens locally, maybe my repo is corrupt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: unable to create symlink (File name too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411200/git-unable-to-create-symlink-file-name-too-long)