# Publishing create-react-app to Azure getting git checkout error when running pipeline how can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, git, azure, azure-pipelines, checkout

I'm new to Microsoft Azure DevOps and I'm trying to run a new pipeline I created. I have the git repo connected to Azure and can few the repo files there, the react app is within an nested folder. I have set the npm agent tasks to use this folder as the working folder though. When I run the pipeline I get this error under 'Checkout Fridge Manager@main to s'. Firstly, I don't have a branch called s so I'm wondering if maybe there is a typo there, here is the log: (I have removed some lines which are just recieving objects to be able to post entire log I believe the problem will be found in other lines)

I would also like to say apologies for any incorrect use of terminology or tagging, I have no idea what I'm doing here I'm just trying to deploy a school project web app i've been working on.

Thanks!

```
2021-04-28T17:45:25.8626110Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout Fridge Manager@main to s
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9465528Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9466491Z Task         : Get sources
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9467041Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9467344Z Version      : 1.0.0
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9467851Z Author       : Microsoft
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9468476Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2021-04-28T17:45:25.9468784Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-28T17:45:26.8397133Z Syncing repository: Fridge Manager (Git)
2021-04-28T17:45:26.8402578Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2021-04-28T17:45:26.8410877Z ##[command]git version
2021-04-28T17:45:28.0767537Z git version 2.30.2.windows.1
2021-04-28T17:45:28.0967318Z ##[command]git lfs version
2021-04-28T17:45:29.6589513Z git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
2021-04-28T17:45:29.6784995Z ##[command]git init "D:\a\1\s"
2021-04-28T17:45:29.8401632Z Initialized empty Git repository in D:/a/1/s/.git/
2021-04-28T17:45:29.8464094Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://yourfrm@dev.azure.com/yourfrm/Fridge%AZP2520Manager/_git/Fridge%AZP2520Manager
2021-04-28T17:45:29.9173545Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2021-04-28T17:45:29.9770449Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://yourfrm@dev.azure.com/yourfrm/Fridge%AZP2520Manager/_git/Fridge%AZP2520Manager.extraheader
2021-04-28T17:45:30.0118375Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2021-04-28T17:45:30.0467645Z ##[command]git config http.version HTTP/1.1
2021-04-28T17:45:30.0904266Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2021-04-28T17:45:32.0816205Z remote: Azure Repos        
2021-04-28T17:45:32.1297578Z remote: 
2021-04-28T17:45:32.1299469Z remote: Found 65564 objects to send. (49 ms)        
2021-04-28T17:45:32.3644710Z Receiving objects:   0% (1/65564)
2021-04-28T17:45:32.3841953Z Receiving objects:   1% (656/65564)
2021-04-28T17:45:32.4112249Z Receiving objects:   2% (1312/65564)
2021-04-28T17:45:32.4462953Z Receiving objects:   3% (1967/65564)
2021-04-28T17:45:32.4893476Z Receiving objects:   4% (2623/65564)
2021-04-28T17:45:34.6756864Z Receiving objects:  45% (29504/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.6766905Z Receiving objects:  46% (30160/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.6866758Z Receiving objects:  47% (30816/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.6953354Z Receiving objects:  48% (31471/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7085459Z Receiving objects:  49% (32127/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7183758Z Receiving objects:  50% (32782/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7292069Z Receiving objects:  51% (33438/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7429155Z Receiving objects:  52% (34094/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7568477Z Receiving objects:  53% (34749/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7711587Z Receiving objects:  54% (35405/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7762780Z Receiving objects:  55% (36061/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7784221Z Receiving objects:  56% (36716/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7828930Z Receiving objects:  57% (37372/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7894278Z Receiving objects:  58% (38028/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7916528Z Receiving objects:  59% (38683/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7933536Z Receiving objects:  60% (39339/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7961836Z Receiving objects:  61% (39995/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.7981886Z Receiving objects:  62% (40650/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8004016Z Receiving objects:  63% (41306/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8024614Z Receiving objects:  64% (41961/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8051420Z Receiving objects:  65% (42617/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8065817Z Receiving objects:  66% (43273/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8077062Z Receiving objects:  67% (43928/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8090241Z Receiving objects:  68% (44584/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8106746Z Receiving objects:  69% (45240/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8119671Z Receiving objects:  70% (45895/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8144190Z Receiving objects:  71% (46551/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8164688Z Receiving objects:  72% (47207/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8198133Z Receiving objects:  73% (47862/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8209404Z Receiving objects:  74% (48518/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8240615Z Receiving objects:  75% (49173/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8266383Z Receiving objects:  76% (49829/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8288462Z Receiving objects:  77% (50485/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8298451Z Receiving objects:  78% (51140/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8308389Z Receiving objects:  79% (51796/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8319253Z Receiving objects:  80% (52452/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8331123Z Receiving objects:  81% (53107/65564), 47.76 MiB | 23.88 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8351993Z Receiving objects:  82% (53763/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8367890Z Receiving objects:  83% (54419/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8386340Z Receiving objects:  84% (55074/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.8649675Z Receiving objects:  85% (55730/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.9080043Z Receiving objects:  86% (56386/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.9135559Z Receiving objects:  87% (57041/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.9213525Z Receiving objects:  88% (57697/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:34.9391624Z Receiving objects:  89% (58352/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8619187Z Receiving objects:  90% (59008/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8620971Z Receiving objects:  91% (59664/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8622114Z Receiving objects:  92% (60319/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8644046Z Receiving objects:  93% (60975/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8644496Z Receiving objects:  94% (61631/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8644969Z Receiving objects:  95% (62286/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8645338Z Receiving objects:  96% (62942/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8645689Z Receiving objects:  97% (63598/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8646038Z Receiving objects:  98% (64253/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8646405Z Receiving objects:  99% (64909/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8646834Z Receiving objects: 100% (65564/65564), 63.85 MiB | 25.54 MiB/s
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8647208Z Receiving objects: 100% (65564/65564), 68.46 MiB | 25.57 MiB/s, done.
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8647574Z Resolving deltas:   0% (0/33807)
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8749950Z Resolving deltas:  97% (32793/33807)
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8750359Z Resolving deltas:  98% (33131/33807)
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8750667Z Resolving deltas:  99% (33469/33807)
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8751065Z Resolving deltas: 100% (33807/33807)
2021-04-28T17:45:35.8751370Z Resolving deltas: 100% (33807/33807), done.
2021-04-28T17:45:36.2550622Z From https://dev.azure.com/yourfrm/Fridge%20Manager/_git/Fridge%20Manager
2021-04-28T17:45:36.2551234Z  * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
2021-04-28T17:45:36.2555682Z  * [new branch]      v0.3       -> origin/v0.3
2021-04-28T17:45:36.2556157Z  * [new branch]      v0.5       -> origin/v0.5
2021-04-28T17:45:36.3418001Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd:refs/remotes/origin/770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd
2021-04-28T17:45:36.4600145Z From https://dev.azure.com/yourfrm/Fridge%20Manager/_git/Fridge%20Manager
2021-04-28T17:45:36.4604664Z  * [new ref]             770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd -> origin/770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd
2021-04-28T17:45:36.5223788Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6486271Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/ansi-html: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6500074Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6503359Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/babylon: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6506941Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/browserslist: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6508982Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/css-blank-pseudo: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6511647Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/css-has-pseudo: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6514517Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/css-prefers-color-scheme: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6523171Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/detect: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6523749Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6530835Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/detect-port: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6540891Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/escodegen: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6543546Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/esgenerate: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6548248Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/eslint: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6550903Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/esparse: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6553417Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6560537Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/html-minifier-terser: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6563208Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/import-local-fixture: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6582630Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/jest-runtime: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6587644Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/js-yaml: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6609030Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/loose-envify: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6612273Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/miller-rabin: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6627602Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/multicast-dns: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6630261Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/nanoid: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6632671Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6636972Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6638928Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/nodetouch: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6648326Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/parser: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6655299Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6657929Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/regjsparser: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6668990Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/rollup: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6676206Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6717579Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/uuid: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6720047Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/watch: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6722684Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/webpack: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6723560Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.6906049Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.7016824Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:36.8383000Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:37.8173610Z Updating files:   4% (2681/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:37.9189278Z Updating files:   5% (2972/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:37.9190233Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:38.1305406Z Updating files:   6% (3567/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:38.2352825Z Updating files:   7% (4161/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:38.3731635Z Updating files:   8% (4755/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:38.5893275Z Updating files:   9% (5350/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:38.6407339Z Updating files:  10% (5944/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:38.9867027Z Updating files:  10% (6173/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.1734574Z Updating files:  11% (6538/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.1741058Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/core-js-compat/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:39.2914923Z Updating files:  12% (7133/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.3930896Z Updating files:  13% (7727/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.5006915Z Updating files:  14% (8321/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.6429688Z Updating files:  15% (8916/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.6637339Z Updating files:  15% (9366/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.7986017Z Updating files:  16% (9510/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:39.9568170Z Updating files:  17% (10104/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:40.4196524Z Updating files:  18% (10699/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:40.6435056Z Updating files:  19% (11293/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:40.7311679Z Updating files:  19% (11639/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:40.9313227Z Updating files:  20% (11887/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:41.0910596Z Updating files:  21% (12482/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:41.2944819Z Updating files:  22% (13076/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:41.3438997Z Updating files:  23% (13670/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:41.3440740Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/.bin/node-which: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:41.7125319Z Updating files:  23% (14080/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:41.9318305Z Updating files:  24% (14265/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:42.1695475Z Updating files:  25% (14859/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:42.2727264Z Updating files:  26% (15453/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:42.2728723Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:42.2916335Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/jest-changed-files/node_modules/.bin/node-which: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:42.5220170Z Updating files:  27% (16048/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:42.5221119Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/jest/node_modules/.bin/jest: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:42.6566115Z Updating files:  27% (16623/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.1829786Z Updating files:  28% (16642/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.2709150Z Updating files:  29% (17236/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.4887185Z Updating files:  30% (17831/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.5511762Z Updating files:  31% (18425/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.5513583Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/node-notifier/node_modules/.bin/node-which: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:43.7521722Z Updating files:  31% (18708/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.7662134Z Updating files:  32% (19019/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:43.7663448Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:44.5742143Z Updating files:  33% (19614/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:44.5808956Z Updating files:  34% (20208/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:44.5810860Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/.bin/browserslist: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:44.5814981Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/.bin/node-which: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:44.6404259Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:44.7481073Z Updating files:  34% (20387/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:44.9967077Z Updating files:  35% (20802/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:45.1040483Z Updating files:  36% (21397/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:45.1042310Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/semver-diff/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:45.7060691Z Updating files:  37% (21991/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:45.7545435Z Updating files:  37% (22457/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:46.0274246Z Updating files:  38% (22585/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:46.2241508Z Updating files:  39% (23180/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:46.2242091Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/.bin/import-local-fixture: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:46.2245589Z error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/backend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/.bin/semver: Filename too long
2021-04-28T17:45:46.5726069Z Updating files:  40% (23774/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:46.6473960Z Updating files:  41% (24368/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:46.7819573Z Updating files:  41% (24602/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:47.3584200Z Updating files:  42% (24963/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:47.5507999Z Updating files:  43% (25557/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:47.6468982Z Updating files:  44% (26151/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:47.8455464Z Updating files:  44% (26369/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:48.2025683Z Updating files:  45% (26746/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:48.6707857Z Updating files:  46% (27340/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:48.9581994Z Updating files:  47% (27934/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:49.1422495Z Updating files:  48% (28529/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:49.2685398Z Updating files:  49% (29123/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:49.3766221Z Updating files:  50% (29717/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:49.6100680Z Updating files:  51% (30312/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:49.6558583Z Updating files:  52% (30906/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.0190160Z Updating files:  52% (31000/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.2155341Z Updating files:  53% (31501/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.3989281Z Updating files:  54% (32095/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.5219635Z Updating files:  55% (32689/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.6656733Z Updating files:  56% (33284/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.7453628Z Updating files:  56% (33626/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:50.8807518Z Updating files:  57% (33878/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:51.1094825Z Updating files:  58% (34472/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:51.4906863Z Updating files:  59% (35067/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:51.6565300Z Updating files:  60% (35661/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5761550Z Updating files:  60% (36080/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5763472Z Updating files:  61% (36255/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5763950Z Updating files:  62% (36850/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5764398Z Updating files:  63% (37444/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5764832Z Updating files:  63% (37899/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5765239Z Updating files:  64% (38038/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.5765648Z Updating files:  65% (38633/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.6032000Z Updating files:  66% (39227/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:53.6541233Z Updating files:  67% (39821/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:54.1497828Z Updating files:  67% (39934/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:54.4110088Z Updating files:  68% (40416/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:54.6545980Z Updating files:  69% (41010/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:54.7034982Z Updating files:  69% (41501/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:54.9632744Z Updating files:  70% (41604/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:55.1212280Z Updating files:  71% (42199/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:55.4723408Z Updating files:  72% (42793/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:55.6548713Z Updating files:  73% (43387/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:55.6590953Z Updating files:  73% (43975/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:55.9621905Z Updating files:  74% (43982/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:56.1723275Z Updating files:  75% (44576/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:56.4844339Z Updating files:  76% (45170/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:56.7418948Z Updating files:  77% (45765/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:57.0147588Z Updating files:  77% (45832/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:57.2746805Z Updating files:  78% (46359/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:57.4582939Z Updating files:  79% (46953/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:57.6579113Z Updating files:  80% (47548/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:57.7625065Z Updating files:  80% (47867/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:58.2919778Z Updating files:  81% (48142/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:58.5677941Z Updating files:  82% (48736/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:58.6567662Z Updating files:  83% (49331/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:58.8568999Z Updating files:  83% (49479/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:59.1493610Z Updating files:  84% (49925/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:59.5855245Z Updating files:  85% (50519/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:59.6572356Z Updating files:  86% (51114/59434)
2021-04-28T17:45:59.8304068Z Updating files:  86% (51368/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:00.0435791Z Updating files:  87% (51708/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:00.2936997Z Updating files:  88% (52302/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:00.6565056Z Updating files:  89% (52897/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:00.6592409Z Updating files:  90% (53491/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.0725361Z Updating files:  90% (53492/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.3365172Z Updating files:  91% (54085/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.5971283Z Updating files:  92% (54680/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.6577148Z Updating files:  93% (55274/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.6952935Z Updating files:  93% (55588/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:01.8543096Z Updating files:  94% (55868/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:02.7725194Z Updating files:  95% (56463/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:02.9544195Z Updating files:  95% (56685/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:03.2562953Z Updating files:  96% (57057/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:03.6591771Z Updating files:  97% (57651/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:03.7298801Z Updating files:  97% (58070/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:03.9978079Z Updating files:  98% (58246/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:04.3046252Z Updating files:  99% (58840/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:04.3048177Z Updating files: 100% (59434/59434)
2021-04-28T17:46:04.3048896Z Updating files: 100% (59434/59434), done.
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4599157Z Note: switching to '770bb71907a1d491b4ce561d45cb02cfdd03e1cd'.
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4599398Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4599686Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4600117Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4600484Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4600644Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4600926Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4601302Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4601487Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4601713Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4601829Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4602043Z Or undo this operation with:
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4602164Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4604590Z   git switch -
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4719591Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4720163Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4720449Z 
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4720904Z HEAD is now at 770bb7190 Submit SHA updated
2021-04-28T17:46:04.4827567Z ##[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
2021-04-28T17:46:04.5108499Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout Fridge Manager@main to s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could output the [predefined System variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`, and will find its value looks like `c:\agent_work\1\s`. The `s` mean the source folder and its meaning is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. Thus why you see `Checkout Fridge Manager@main to s`.

In addition, this error `error: unable to create symlink Fridge Manager v0.5/mern-proto-app/***: Filename too long` seems to be caused by Git limitation when checkout the file and its file path is too long. You could copy the react app to the root directory instead of an nested folder and then check the result. In other hand, it might be caused broken symlink by reference to this doc: [Git: unable to create symlink (File name too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411200/git-unable-to-create-symlink-file-name-too-long). You could try to checkout this repo locally to confirm this point.

Comment: Hi Joe, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.