# How can I track changes against a subdirectory of a git repository?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am working on some client modifications to a module within a PHP web application. I have access to the upstream source in a git repo, and I would like to track our changes in our own git repo.

The full source repo is huge (in comparison to the module) so I would prefer to extract the module (contained in two subdirectories) in our repo... but I would like to be able to merge in any upstream changes in the future.

If I was in control of the upstream repo I would spin the module off into a subtree. But I'm not, so I can't!

### My best solution so far

Initialise my own repo:

```
mkdir myrepo
cd myrepo
git init .
git touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Initialise repo"
```

Then add the upstream repo as a remote:

```
git remote add -f upstream /path/to/upstream/repo
```

Track (and checkout for good measure) the upstream code as a branch:

```
git checkout -b upstream upstream/master
```

Merge the upstream branch, as a subtree, into my master branch:

```
git checkout master
git subtree add --prefix vendor/upstream upstream --squash
```

Then create my own src directory with symlinks to the upstream directories I want to work on:

```
mkdir src
cd src
ln -s ../vendor/upstream/path/to/directory1 .
ln -s ../vendor/upstream/path/to/directory2 .
```

### Why do it this way?

I now have a src directory which just represents the module I want to work on. I can commit my changes to my repo, yet still merge in upstream changes (by refreshing the vendor subtree).

However, this does not seem very elegant. I am carrying the entire upstream codebase in my repo even though I only care about two subdirectories.

### What else have I tried?

I initially tried using sparseCheckout to restrict the directories pulled in from upstream. It appeared to do exactly what I wanted on my box, but the repo still contained all of the upstream code. What is more, the sparseCheckout settings do not replicate when the repo is cloned.

### What I want

Is there a better/more elegant solution to this problem? I realise the ideal is to spin out a sub-repo upstream, but I can't do that. I don't really need to track upstream version history... apart from the fact I want to easily merge in upstream changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS supports symlinks (i.e is not Windows): Create the module repo somewhere else, and create symlinks to the two directories you want to use in your code. When you want to pull down module changes, cd to the module repo and pull into there. When you want to push up changes from your own code, it looks from [the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) like Git would do exactly what you want.