# How to use git subtree with repo tool?

Tags: git, version-control, symlink, repository

I have a root git directory. I would like to put under the root directory another independent git repository as subdirectory.

I am using [repo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo_%28script%29) so I can't use [submoudles](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). I thought to make a subdirectory symbolic linked to a far stand alone directory. The far outside directory will contain the new git repository.

I saw there is another option [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) using `git subtree`.

1. Can I use it when working with the repo tool?
2. Is it better to use subtree than the symbolic link solution?

Answer (score 0):

`subtree`, unlike `submodule`, doesn't require any additional steps to get the source code of a subdirectory it manages. That is, simple `git clone` or `git checkout` will "deliver" all of the contents of a directory managed with `subtree`. Therefore any tool which works with Git should be fine with subtrees, including Repo (although I didn't personally try it with subtrees exactly).

Note, however, that to update a directory managed with a subtree, one still needs to do it manually. That is, the commit to whcih a subtree points to is stored into the Git repository itself, and can only be updated manually with `git subtree merge` or `git subtree pull` again.

Think of a subtree-managed directory as if it is any other directory in the repository. The only thing `subtree` adds - is that it allows merging other branches (including remote ones) into a specific prefix (that is into a subdirectory). And does it very well.

Using synlinks to external repositories may not work - see another SO answer on this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507967/302343.