# git fetch/pull file "becomes" symbolic link

Tags: git

I have a private git repo, access with ssh. ( eg `git@myhost.com:/home/git` )

There is a PHP project in it. My develop & deploy machine is both linux. It's works well for about half a year.

But these days, when I run `git pull`(or `clone` to other place), files in project root "becomes" symbolic link.

Hard to explain. So paste these:

---

`ls -al`

Some of output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 nginx nginx 4096 Jan 20 22:08 App
drwxr-xr-x 10 nginx nginx 4096 Jan 20 22:08 .git
drwxr-xr-x 10 nginx nginx 4096 Jan 20 22:08 Core
lrwxrwxrwx 10 nginx nginx 4096 Jan 20 22:06 index.php -> <?phpdefine('APP_PATH','./App');define(..........(FULL content OF index.php)
lrwxrwxrwx 10 nginx nginx 4096 Jan 20 22:08 .gitignore -> # ide.idea#temp files_runtime*.log..........(FULL content OF gitignore)
```

I know linux symbollic link is a file that contains the "target file path" and have a special "flag".

Every time I `pull`/`reset` , `git` will mark these files as symbollic links (which is really a normal file), and I don't know how to remove that flag.

This only occurs for files in project root (beside `.git` dir), **for ALL of them**.

Can someone help me with what's happened to my git repo?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and confirm all those files are symlinks with:

```
 git ls-files -s ./aFile
 120000 1596f9db1b9610f238b78dd168ae33faa2dec15c 0       aFile
```

You should see them with a `120000` mode in the index, referencing an hash of the actual object content, which you can see with a:

```
git cat-file -p 1596f9db1
```

See "[What does git do to files that are a symbolic link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/6309)"

You could try and restore all the files that way (removing the file from the index, recreating with the content of the `cat-file -p` command).

But I would rather check the history of the repo and see if I cannot reset to a state where those files were recorded as actual files, instead of symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason.....

I'm using both WebStorm & PhpStorm on the same project.

Two IDE using different version of plugins and different workspace staus (opened files etc)

So the .idea directory must different, I make another dir, soft link all file&folders except ".idea" in the project root to another dir.

Normaly I use PhpStrom's Git gui to upload my files, Weeks ago, I push a commit using WebStorm .

Finally, I get my files back using:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec bash -c -t 'mv "{}" "{}".bak ; readlink "{}.bak">"{}" ; rm -f "{}.bak"' \;`