# Adding new files and symlinks in github

Tags: git, github

I have the following files and symlinks  in my directory. My question is how to add symlinks
.Should i do the following.All the files and symlinks are new files which are yet to be committed for the first time

```
git add s1 s2 readme.txt
```

then do

```
git commit -m ""
git push origin master
```

Following are the files I have

```
s1 -> readme.txt
s2 -> readme.txt
```

Comment: Yes, the steps you mentioned will work. Note that if you are later on forking the repo to windows, symlinks won't work there.

Comment: checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the steps you have mentioned will work.  (`git add s1 s2 readme.txt && git commit -m "commit message" && git push origin master`)

Note that if you are later on forking the repo to windows, symlinks won't work there.

PS: You will have to give some commit message, otherwise your current empty string commit message will get the following error

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```