# How can I deploy 2 rails apps from a single Git repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I have 2 rails applications that live inside the same git repo.

There is a shared folder where common logic lives.

```
- app_1

- shared

- app_2
```

The `shared` folder is really just a symlink to the appropriate places inside the `app_1` folder. There is also a `shared_public` folder that is symlinked to `app_1/public/files` and `app_2/public/files`.

How can I do this? I'm open to anything, it's a clean slate. The project was never deployed previously, so I don't have a existing infrastructure to rely on. And splitting the shared logic out is (unfortunately) not an option currently, because of the timeframe I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

**Git**

When you mention the `shared` folder is a [`symlink`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) - this *only* exists in operating systems, not `git`

Since `git` is just a deployment mechanism in this instance (I.E will place your files from your `repo` onto your server), you'll probably be able to do the following:

> - Initialize a `git` repo on your server (`$ git init` on your server)
> - Clone your `github` repo locally (`git clone https://github.com....` on your local box)
> - CD into your new folder and [add the server's repo as a remote](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)
> - `$ git push [server repo name] master`

This isn't what you want, I know.

It will push your files onto your server - so you'll get the following folder structure:

- `app1`
- `app2`

The `shared` folder could then be created on your server itself.

If you have your appropriate server setup, you should be able to get this running from performing these steps

---

**Capistrano**

If you want to use Capistrano, you'll have to do something a little more involved, as this does more than just push your files to your server

If you want to use `Capistrano`, you'll have to split your `app1` and `app2` into separate applications, and deploy them individually. This will still allow you to create a symlink on your server, except you'll have a slightly different structure to your directories

Comment: [Git understands symlinks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/3785131). It stores the relative path in the directory. And the capistrano section is no help, what do you mean by "into separate applications"? Do I need to split them out into different git repos?

Comment: My apologies - seems like I was wrong! I would personally split into different git repos sorry

Comment: So how would I do this? Would I have `app1`, `app2`, and `shared`, and then keep them all in sync via submodules, or should I use [subtrees](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)?

Comment: That's what I considered at the beginning. However, I wasn't able to convince myself that was sustainable.

Comment: Well it depends on what you're trying to do. When you say you have "shared functionality" - what do you have? EG couldn't you create a `gem`?

Comment: Database models (this gives me nightmares), some business logic and a few homegrown libraries. I'm working on splitting the homegrown libs out, but still leaves me with the business logic and models.

Comment: Hmm okay - got any case examples?

Comment: The contents of `app1/app/models` is shared with app - app2 has *no* models that app1 doesn't have.