# Files are links after pulling from git

Tags: git, macos

For some reason when I pull change with three files, I have them as broken links:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff         7 Jul 16 00:44 lib_3.so -> ?ELF???
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff         7 Jul 16 00:44 lib_2.so -> ?ELF???
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff         7 Jul 16 00:45 lib_1.so -> ?ELF???
```

If I manually download real files from git server and replace them - everything is ok.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, check on the server side if the files are symlinks. Committing a symlink to the repository will just put the link in the repo (not the actual file). http://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/151344

Comment: No, it is bitbucket.com service. I could see only file name, size in web UI.