# Commiting openssl MAKE solution using git under windows fails due to symbolic links

Tags: windows, git, openssl, tortoisegit

Once i try adding / commiting openssl(taken from openssl.org) using git's gui, everything gets stuck and non-responsive for a couple of minutes until I'm promoted with this error:

```
error readlink(..md4.c) function not implemented, unable to process file md4.c .. symbolic link
```

What's the proper way of adding openssl using git?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing on the git command line? Git should just [treat the symlink as a symlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) (a pointer to a file) without worrying about the fact that it's a symlink.

Comment: @merlin2011 when i try 'git add openssl-1.0.2.d]' it generates the same error.
'error: readlink... not implemented, unable to index file ....\aes.h' which is a symbolic link

Comment: is it possible somehow to replace symbolic files with their real files instead?