# Git SourceTree:shows symbolic link files as unstaged file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am currently attempting to push a library called Mono to my repository.
I am using SourceTree for managing the git repository.
I noticed that the library had some symbolic link files in it.
Now After adding the library to my repository. Source tree told me that the newly added content is currently unstaged. I selected all the files and placed them in the staged section. Now I noticed that certain files are still showing up in the unstaged section and these files are symbolic links.If I try to add them by clicking on a file I get the following error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree rm -q -f -- MyFolder/mono/compile 
fatal: pathspec 'MyFolder/mono/compile' did not match any files
Completed with errors, see above
```

My question is how should I handle such a situation.Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links) link it seems git stores the symbolic links as blobs and generates them when the repository is cloned.In that case if the symbolic links are showing up (after I have pushed the commit) as Unstaged Files should i simply mark them as "ignore those files". Will that be safe ?