# How to share React components between two Meteor apps in the same repository?

Tags: git, meteor, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

I have two apps (public-app and admin-app) that share some React components. Those shared components are situated in a `common` folder, at the root of the repository. So let's say I have:

```
my-app
  |__admin-app
     |__client
        |__imports
           |__Component.js
  |__public-app
  |__common
     |__SharedComponent.js
```

In `Component.js`, I try to import `SharedComponent.js` by doing:

`import SharedComponent from '../../../common/SharedComponent'`

...But it's not working, it cannot find the module.

This should be possible as it is one of the recommended approaches from the official documentation (https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#sharing-code), so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with symbolic link?

Comment: are you exporting default?

Comment: @MasterAM: There's nothing wrong, it's just that here, with my Meteor project, it's not working when I try to import something out of the current Meteor app.

Comment: @vijayst: yes, I'm exporting default.

Comment: You should link to the module from within your project. `ln -s ../common/` or something similar, such that it becomes a directory within your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [babel](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code, I solve this problem by using the `root-import` plugin. You could look this plugin to help you with requiring your files using the same syntax to point to the same folder.

With babel plugins, I would suggest looking into [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias) or [babel-root-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-import).

### module alias

With module-alias, your `.babelrc` would look something like this:

```
{
    "presets" : ["es2015", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "module-alias",
            [
                { "src": "./my-app", "expose": "my-app" },
            ]
        ]
    ],
}
```

..and you could then use the syntax `import SharedComponent from 'my-app/common/SharedComponent'`*.

### root import

Or with root-import your `.babelrc` would be something like:

```
{
    "presets" : ["es2015", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        ["babel-root-import"]
    ]
}
```

..and you could then use the syntax `import SharedComponent from '~/my-app/common/SharedComponent'*.

*as long as you are using a babelrc file and that `my-app` is the root of your project.

Answer (score -1):

Meteor users: don't forget to put all your exported files in the "imports" folder, even if used through a symlink. I had an error of undefined variable because Meteor was trying to eagerly load my files put in my `common` folder.

So, follow @bitten advice and start by creating the symlink. Git should handle that nicely (cf. [How does git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links)): `ln -s ../common/`

Then, you can use https://github.com/mantrajs/babel-root-slash-import which is actually a fork from `babel-root-import` to simplify your import paths. (thanks @bitten).