# How to save a the files of a symbolic link folder in git hub?

Tags: git, github

Here the structure of my folders :

- library
- Project 1

  - srcs
  - objs
  - lib -> ../library
- Project 2

  - srcs
  - objs
  - lib -> ../library

As you can see, for all my projects, I use a personal library in the main folder called "library".
I have no problem to use it that way for my compilation ... and I have the advantage to keep update the library folder for all my programs without modify each folder inside of each project.
Unfortunately, when I save in git hub it doesn't save my files in `library`.
I have a folder with a `symbolic link` but nothing inside.

How could I do to save the entire folder in my github repo ?
I would like to be able, when I download an archive to get the full program with the library inside.

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How git handle symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links)

with that:

**Option 1:**

Wrap `Project 1`, `Project 2` and `library` to a wrapping folder and initiate git repository there:

```
ParentDirectory
  .git
  library
  Project 1
     .git
     src
     objs
     liblink 
  Project 2
     .git
     src
     objs
     liblink
```

You can use .gitignore so it will not track Project 1 and Project 2 if you want to maintain the current git files for each project

**Option 2:**

Initiate git for `library`

```
library
   .git
   contents
Project 1
   .git
   src
   objs
   liblink 
Project 2
   .git
   src
   objs
   liblink
```