# symbolic link data lost in git

Tags: git, version-control, symlink

Someone in my Team created a symbolic link and committed it to git. I need to clone this project, update the symbolic link and commit it back. However when I did git clone, I don't see the file as symbolic link when I run "ls -al" command.It appears as a normal directory. I can see that file as a symbolic link on bit-bucket but not on UNIX box. Does symbolic link data get lost when we do git pull? How can I update the symbolic link if I don't even see that file as a symbolic link?

I have already seen this and it didn't answer my question.
[How does git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 2):

As you found, **the symbolic link file is still exist after you cloned/pulled**. Please check if you let the hidden file to show, such as if you can see the .git folder.
If you still can’t see the symbolic link file, you can use below ways to read/write the contents:

```
cat filename                # show the file content
echo 'message' >> filename  # add messge in the end of the content
vim filename                # edit the content more freely
```