# gitignore inside Symlink folder

Tags: git, yii2, symlink, gitignore

I'm here with a problem that I can not solve!
I am using the Yii2 Advanced framework and create a symbolic link for a folder, inside that folder I have two files and one of them is a gitignore file.
Here is my working tree:

`backend
        web
                uploads       <- symbolic link`


`frontend
        web
                uploads       <- original folder
                        index.php
                        .gitignore`

When I try to stash from my working tree git returns the following:
`error: 'backend / web / uploads / .gitignore' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: Unable to process path backend / web / uploads / .gitignore
Can not save the current worktree state`

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links), you can track a symlink by itself, but content behind it. you can however move the ignore file outside the folder and have your uploads folder ignored completely

Comment: a better solution actually is to leave the original as is, and completely ignore the symlink (add `/backend/web/uploads` to your root .gitignore file)