# Go microservice in project and monolit git repository

Tags: git, go, microservices, directory-structure

Let's say I want to write one of my microservices in a project with go and I also want to keep monolit git repository for the whole project. The problem is that such microservice should be located under GOPATH and I can't even symlink it into my project cause git doesn't support symlinks.
What are options to keep the monolit repository for project while having go microservices in it?

Edit:
I mean what the best practice to keep go microservice in git for non-golang project.

Comment: Git does support symlinks.

Comment: @Flimzy accrording to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/1180020 it doesn't. i mean it doesn't count symlink to dir as dir

Answer (score 1):

Just for simplicity suppose: project is located in `/Users/user/Workspace/Monorepo/go-microservice` checked out from github repo `github.com/Company/Monorepo`.

Make symlink from another side: from GOPATH to required folder. Your repo is kept in standard space and GO can see code with its usual path.

Thus make in folder `/Users/user/go/src/github.com/Company` symlink `Monorepo` pointing to first path.

Comment: So the go pkg directory wouldn't be in the git repository. Is it the right choice?

Comment: @mirt yes, you do not need `pkg` in git repo. Only source code.

Comment: That has more to do with git not supporting directories.