# CMake: How to reuse the same test_main.cpp for each test

Tags: c++, cmake, catch-unit-test

I would like to use the test framework [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) in a monorepo in which there will be many components, each with their own tests. I'd like to use CMake to define all build targets.

Catch2 [provides a simple means](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#scaling-up) to generate a common `main()` function that will run all tests linked into the application. The source file (which I am calling `test_main.cpp`) is just these two lines:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
```

I'd like to have just one copy of `test_main.cpp` in my source tree, and refer to it from each component directory that has tests (which will end up being on the order of hundreds of directories).

I can see how to set up CMake to work if I duplicated the `test_main.cpp` so that a redundant copy existed in each directory with tests, but I haven't figured out how to have just one copy. Is there a simple trick I've overlooked?

Comment: [Git can handle symlinks FWIW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links).

Comment: I would check the Catch's logic to find out where it looks for test sources. Since they are all plain C code (i.e. Catch seems to only kick in after compilation), I guess it's as simple as adding another compilation unit to a project.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `test_main.cpp` to each `add_executable` line?  You'd probably need the full path to the file, but something like `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_main.cpp` (assuming you have `test_main.cpp` at the top level of your project) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try integrating Catch2 as a CMake [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) in the following way:

Add the single header file `catch.hpp` and `test_main.cpp` to a directory of their own (e.g.,  `Catch2`) along with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(catch INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(catch INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)
target_sources(catch INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_main.cpp")
```

The in your outermost `CMakeLists.txt` include Catch2 with `add_subdirectory`:

```
add_subdirectory(Catch2)
```

You can then set up test executables anywhere in the project in the following way:

```
add_executable(
    project_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
    test_case1.cpp
    test_case2.cpp
    ...
)

target_link_libraries(project_tests catch)
```

Because `test_main.cpp` has been added to `catch` as an interface source file, it will be compiled as part of the test executable.

Comment: This looks good. I'll give it try and approve the answer after I've verified that it works. Thanks.

Comment: in fact we do not need to copy catch.hpp and put it to a directory with test_main.cpp, we can just have test_main.cpp in the folder and write CMakeLists.txt like:```  add_library(catch test_main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(catch PUBLIC Catch2::Catch2)
```