# Laravel use S3/CloudFront resources in Blade

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.5, amazon-cloudfront

I'm a bit confused about what the best approach is in order to access an image, which is uploaded to S3 and delivered via CloudFront and show it in a view (using the CloudFront URL). I use `Laravel 5.5` and I deposited the CDN URL already to my S3 configuration:

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => 'https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/',
    ],
```

The following possibilities work

- Copy and paste the CloudFront link into the template (not the laravel way, I guess).
- Using `<img src="{{ Storage::url('assets/img/image.png') }}" />`. This one works, but is it the right approach? The problem here is, that if I change the `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` back to local I can't reference the resources in my `DOCROOT/public/img` folder like I did earlier with `{{ asset('img/icons/time.png') }}`, so I'm loosing flexibility - maybe I need to copy the assets to `DOCROOT/storage/app/public/` which used by the `local` driver?

I'm integrating CloudFront the first time to a Laravel app, so could someone who did that before tell me what the right approach is? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good approach.  But when using the local filesystem driver, you would use the `public/storage/assets/img` directory, not the `public/img` directory to make it equivalent.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk

## The Public Disk

The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

## File URLs

You may use the url method to get the URL for the given file. If you are using the local driver, this will typically just prepend /storage to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. If you are using the s3 or rackspace driver, the fully qualified remote URL will be returned:

Comment: Thank you, Devon. There just one thing I noticed I would do different: The `php artisan storage:link`creates an absolute link, which is not good if you're developing local and then pushing to a remote repository. That's why I created the same link manually, but as a relative one.

Comment: Ah now I saw this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507967/5199242 - so it doesn't matter if the link is absolute, a `git pull` will result in a directory, not a link.

Comment: Yeah, `/public/storage` should be in your gitignore file anyways.