# Git checkout symbolic links correctly

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a git repository which (for some reasons) contains some symbolic links (in unix-like operating systems). However, after I cloned it, each symbolic link is checked out as a regular text file containing the symbolic link destination. How should I let git checkout the links correctly?

A sample run of my command is attached below. In `/tmp/a`, `path` is a symbolic link to `/some/path`. However, in `/tmp/b`, the `path` is a regular file.

```
[user@host /tmp]$ mkdir a
[user@host /tmp]$ cd a
[user@host /tmp/a]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/a/.git/
[user@host /tmp/a]$ ln -s /some/path
[user@host /tmp/a]$ git add path
[user@host /tmp/a]$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   path

[user@host /tmp/a]$ git commit -m 'add path'
[master (root-commit) 8e726b6] add path
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 120000 path
[user@host /tmp/a]$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user group 10 Sep 17 14:35 path -> /some/path
[user@host /tmp/a]$ cd ..
[user@host /tmp]$ git clone file:///tmp/a/.git b
...
[user@host /tmp]$ cd b
[user@host /tmp/b]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 10 Sep 17 14:36 path
[user@host /tmp/b]$ cat path
/some/path[user@host /tmp/b]$ 
[user@host /tmp/b]$
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; `b/path` is a symlink on my system (Mac). Check your [`core.symlinks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresymlinks) setting (`git config --get core.symlinks`). For more details, see [How does Git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links).

Comment: Yes, the check solves my problem. I am using Fedora, and the default setting is `core.symlinks = false`. After I set it to `true`, git handles symbolic links as I expect.

Comment: `core.symlinks` should be set correctly automatically depending on your system when a repository is initialized.  What file system are you using in this case?

Comment: I am using ext4.