# What is the best way to handle codekit config files excluded from repo/server, and still keep devs in sync with the config files?

Tags: git, config, gitignore, codekit

Looking into cleaning up a repo - we are using CodeKit on this project, and want to remove the generated files from the server and repo etc.

But then what is the best way to make sure that other devs on the project use the same CodeKit config files?

We have considered keeping the CodeKit file in dropbox, but then that seems like it would get cumbersome to have to go download it from there anytime someone is working on the project. And hope that they remember to do so...

What are some suggestions for keeping CodeKit config files out of the repo, but keep the development team in sync with using CodeKit, sharing the config file etc?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [Using CodeKit With Git](https://codekitapp.com/help/git/), a `config.codekit3` file could be part of the history of your repository.

If you don't version in the repo itself, then it becomes a tooling issue, with its own deployment/update challenge.
Dropbox (that you mention) should synchronize automatically that file, and you could then add a symbolic link from your project to said synchronized file.
If that file is managed in a folder with a common path on all developers platform, that [symlink can be versioned in your Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/6309).

Answer (score -2):

Go to Codekit > Preferences and check both options under "Pause File-Watching when:"

More about that on https://codekitapp.com/help/git/