# How to bundle asset files from parent directory?

Tags: flutter

We have a git repository in which a sub folder holds a flutter app:

```
project/.git
project/app/*
project/backend/*
```

Now I would like to bundle some files of the `.git` folder in the app:

```yaml
# pubspec.yaml
  assets:
    - ../.git/HEAD
    - ../.git/ORIG_HEAD
    - ../.git/refs/heads/
```

This works when running on an emulator:

```dart
// somewhere in the app:
final _head = await rootBundle.loadString('../.git/HEAD');
```

But when building the app in release mode, the files are not bundled what perfectly makes sense - but I wonder how we can copy/bundle the files.

My naive approach would be to run a script that copies the files to the app folder, but that is brittle as we need to remember to run the script before each build. What would be a more consistent approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this works under windows, but for Linux we can use a symbolic link.

Create a symbolic link for the files that should be bundled in (for example) `project/app/assets/git/*`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p project/app/assets/git/refs
cd project/app/assets
ln -s ../../../.git/HEAD git/HEAD
ln -s ../../../.git/ORIG_HEAD git/ORIG_HEAD
ln -s ../../../../.git/refs/heads git/refs/heads
```

Use it in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
  assets:
    # Note that the `assets/git/**` files are symbolic link to the actual files in `../.git`
    - assets/git/HEAD
    - assets/git/ORIG_HEAD
    - assets/git/refs/heads/
```

Read on here to understand [how git handles symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links) when adding them to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the relative asset and it work on iOS but not on Android.
This is a existing issue in Flutter with Android and it haven't resolved yet.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68983

From this thread, a workaround could be using a separate project.
However, in my case, I did other easy way which is putting the shared file fluter asset folder. Then, other module can refer to this file and we dont get issue with Flutter.
After the the issue was fixed, we can move it to parent folder.