# How to read the content of a symlink as a usual file without resolving it?

Tags: python, c, symlink

A symbolic link is, after all, a file. I wish to open a symbolic link as a plain file, byte by byte, without resolving to the place where it points to. To give an example, `git` does this; see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/954575 for more details

How can I to do this in C or Python?

If I use `fopen` or `open`, then the symlink is automatically resolved. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: So are you looking for C or python?  The answers will be *very* different.

Comment: Not all operating systems support symbolic links.  Presumably you're interested in one that does, but which would that be?

Comment: [`readlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink).

Comment: And `os.readlink()` in Python.

Comment: @dbush I actually wish to know about both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A symbolic link is, after all, a file.

In some sense, yes.  [A symbolic link generally has its own inode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263491/how-is-a-symlink-represented-in-a-file-system-vs-a-hard-link), or is presented as if it did, so it is a file in that sense.  The same is true of a directory.  And of course, in UNIX, *everything* is a file.

But a symbolic link is not a *regular* file.  System interfaces that interact with regular-file contents traverse symbolic links to get to the contents of the file or directory, if any, to which they refer.

> I wish to open a symbolic link as a plain file, byte by byte, without resolving to the place where it points to.

Generally speaking, you can't.  Not from user space.  The OS kernel of course reads the filesystem structures from storage, including the data of inodes representing symbolic links, but the raw data are not exposed to userspace programs via the system interfaces that provide access to regular-file contents.

You can, however, use dedicated interfaces for retrieving a string containing the path to which a symlink points.  The C library function specified by POSIX for this purpose is [`readlink()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html).  You may also have [`realpath()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) available to you, which will perform full path resolution through possibly-many layers of symlinks to an ultimate file.  But neither of these is the same as accessing the data of a symlink as if the symlink were a regular file.

Python has versions of both of those: [`os.readlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.readlink) and [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath).

Comment: Then how does git achieve it?

Comment: @MrUser, Git *does not* achieve what you ask.  It can't.  And it does not need to do so to produce the effect described in the Q&A you linked.  I'd need to review the source to determine for sure what it does instead, but I'm reasonably confident that it's what I described: use `readlink()` to read the link text.

Comment: @MrUser it uses readlink