# How to distinguish symbolic link in git show?

Tags: git

In my git repository I have 2 files committed, one is a symbolic link and another is a regular file

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 4 Mar 13 00:43 a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user group 4 Mar 13 00:43 b -> file
$ cat a
file$ 
$ hexdump -C a
00000000  66 69 6c 65                                       |file|
00000004
$
```

I can use `git show HEAD:a` and `git show HEAD:b` to view the content of these files, and the result are the same

```
$ git show HEAD:a
file
$ git show HEAD:b
file
$ git show HEAD:a | hexdump -C
00000000  66 69 6c 65                                       |file|
00000004
$ git show HEAD:b | hexdump -C
00000000  66 69 6c 65                                       |file|
00000004
$ git show HEAD:
tree HEAD:

a
b
$
```

Is there a way to for `git show` to display the type of the file? Or are there other commands to distinguish between symbolic links and regular files?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links

Comment: Based on that, symlinks should have file mode `120000` instead of something like `100644`. I'm not sure if `git show` has some parameter that would make it show the file mode.