# Does Git have a symbolic link equivalent? Looking to mirror one file in multiple parts of the same repo

Tags: git

Looking to mirror one file in multiple parts of the **same repo**

I've had no luck googling an answer. Maybe I am searching for the wrong terms. plenty of links linking a file in one repo into another, but nothing for what I was looking for

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [How does Git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954560/11082165)

Answer (score 3):

Why is it you want to do this?

If it is to "save space" Git will already save space in the repository -- you don't need to go anything because Git hashes each file and only saves a reference to the file.  If you have the same file in two places Git will only store it once.

If it is to have references to the same file in multiple places while working on the project --  Then just use a symbolic link as normal on you OS.  Your file system will allow you to edit it from multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symbolic link and add it to the repo (using `git add` and `git commit`).