# README extension for Python projects

Tags: python, github

Python packaging tools expect that our readme file should be named README or README.txt. But if we follow this convention, GitHub displays it as plain text in the project page which is not pretty. (unlike the beautiful HTML version when named as README.rst)

Is there any technique to make both PyPI and GitHub happy about README.

Comment: PyPI does *not* expect the file to be named README or README.txt. I don't know what Python packaging tools you mean, but I don't know of any that requires this naming, and if it does it can likely be easily fixed.

Comment: Lennart, when I run `setup.py sdist` without a README, it says `warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt`... but I guess this is just complaint I can ignore?

Comment: @rescdsk: Yes, you can ignore it. AFAIK there is nothing that uses that. In fact, that should really be submitted as a bug report.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11913

Comment: If you would like PyPI to support readmes in Markdown, please comment on the feature request at http://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/148/support-markdown-for-readmes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a [git filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) which would, on checkout, take your `README.md` (needed by GitHub) and generate a proper `README` (needed by Python, although [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/lennart-regebro)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4386698/6309) suggests that PyPI does *not* require any README file)

So, keeping aside the fact that PyPI doesn't need a README (and the warning could be simply ignored), here is how you could (in general) generate the expected file with Git:

[image: smudge clean process]

However, any modification to that private file `README` would need to be reported manually to the `README.md` file (at least because of markdown syntax which no script can guess for you)

That is why [Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384796/readme-extension-for-python-projects/4384952#4384952) (which I upvoted) might be more adapted, especially if you have access to symlinks (I am still with Windows Xp at work, so no luck for me):

Having make `README` being a symlink to `README.rst`, or, as [Arto Bendiken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320911/arto-bendiken) comments:
=> **having `README.rst` being a symlink ro `README`**.

Git will store the symlink (and [not the file the symlink refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500772/getting-git-to-follow-symlinks-again)), so you can have both `README` and its `README.rst` file in your Git repo.

Answer (score 27):

PyPI has no requirement that the file is called README or README.txt, so just call it README.rst. In fact, PyPI will not as far as I'm aware look in your package at all (although I could be wrong there, I haven't studied the code or anything), the text that ends up ion the front is the `long_description` parameter.

Then in your setup.py, you do something like this:

```
setup(name='Your module name',
      version="1.0",
      description="Whatever, dude.",
      long_description=open('docs/README.rst', 'rt').read()
)
```

Comment: Lennart is right.  PyPI can parse reST in long_description, it does not use README.  The warning is just a warning; name your file README or ignore the warning.  packaging/distutils2 is smarter; see the bug report for more info.

Answer (score 11):

A crude way I can think of is to make a symlink to `README` called `README.rst` and check them both in.

Comment: This is what I do, although the other way around: the `README` is a symlink to `README.rst` (or `README.md`, for non-Python projects).

Comment: Yep, I used README.md for github.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting Éric Araujo at the [Python bug about the distutils warning](http://bugs.python.org/issue11913):

> In packaging/distutils2, the recommended idiom looks like this (in setup.cfg):
>
> ```
> [metadata]
> description-file = README.whatever
> ```
>
> sdist will include that file.  You can also write the description in the setup.cfg directly and have your README file included with the extra_files field.

So, basically, ignore the warning from `distutils` about a missing `README.txt`.  Also, `distutils2` supposedly does not emit this warning (I haven't tested), so you could try upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

In older (non-`distutils2`) setups, you can add your `README.rst` to the `MANIFEST.in` file explicitly.  You'll still see a warning about the standard README{.txt} being absent, but your README.rst will be included in your sdist tarball, meaning it will be included for end-users who download directly from PIPY.

See http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template for more details.