# How to have Git 1.6 follow "beyond symlinks"

Tags: git, version-control, symlink, symlink-traversal

Apparently, the bug where git follows and track files beyond symlinks (`git add symlink/`) has been fixed around v1.6. Now this was a bug that works in my favor. Now that we've upgraded to v1.6.3.3, is there any way to reproduce that behavior without downgrading?

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86402/how-can-i-get-git-to-follow-symlinks) discusses both the previous and current behavior without any solution (other than downgrading).

The git mailinglist [at the time of the change](http://n2.nabble.com/Not-going-beyond-symbolic-links-td667979.html) seems to indicate that this "feature" was seriously broken in some ways and most people in that thread argued against keeping it, whatever the cost. So I wouldn't bet on a better solution for now.