# Git: Is it possible to add files located in an external directory to a git repository?

Tags: git

Bare with the following, as I tried to think of a simple example and a common web structure came to mind.  If the structure is like this:

```
/www
   |-- scripts
       |-- js
           `shared_code.js
       `-- css
           `shared_style.css
   |-- images
   `-- cgi-bin/
       |-- projectA
           |-- .git
           |-- foo.php
           `-- foo.pl
       `-- projectB
           |-- .git
           |-- bar.php
           `-- bar.pl
```

Is it possible to add the js/css scripts to the git repositories?

Comment: No. The `.git` directory must be at the top level of your project directories (in this case `www`). Recommend you create a `.git` under `scripts` and then turn the `www` directory into the main repo for the three [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).

Comment: Trying to avoid that.  I think you can do it using symbolic links, but I want to avoid that as well.

Comment: According to an answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86402/how-can-i-get-git-to-follow-symlinks), git doesn't allow for following symlinks since version 1.6.1.

Comment: @Michael: thanks... even my back-up is faulty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you're asking (and it's quite inadvisable anyway).  However, you might look into *submodules*.  Your `projectA` and `projectB` would contain a submodule called `scripts`.  Of course that means you'll have to make `scripts` into its own repository, but that's probably a good thing.  You can read up on submodules here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules