# Git/GitHub: Importing symbolically linked folders

Tags: git, github, symlink

I have my code in different folders, but since I want to view it under one "root" in my IDE, I use symbolic links, e.g. `ln -s /path/to/mode/code/ SomeFolder`. If I try to push into GitHub, only the symbolic link's file gets pushed. How can I make it also import the linked folder and its contents?

Comment: possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get git to follow symlinks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86402/how-can-i-get-git-to-follow-symlinks)

Comment: Related to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43596146/1454514