# GitHub keeps throwing "Could not commit submodules" error, and I don't see why that is. Any ideas?

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to put my project on GitHub, but I keep running into an issue. I made a repo on GitHub (the website), downloaded the client, cloned (dragged and dropped the link GitHub gave me basically) it in, moved my project in the clone directory, and I still didn't see the files. So I checked under "Changes", and found my project files. Now it's saying "Could not commit submodules". How do I fix this?

Here's a screenshot if anyone needs it:

[image: Error]

Due to being too long here is [the log in its entirety](http://pastebin.com/FgHTWA3Y).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your project was itself a git repo (meaning it has a .git), the presence of the .git could confuse the GitHub Desktop client.
It could be seen as a [nested git repo (for which only the gitlink is recorded)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667881/6309), and the GUI tries to see it as a submodule.

Try with command line (unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want and add it to your `%PATH%`)

```
cd /your/project
git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/<yourrepo>
git push
```

Then reference that same project directory in GitHub Desktop: it will be recognized as a local repo linked to a GitHub one.

---

Update 2018, as mentioned by [t3chb0t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235671/t3chb0t) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728070/github-keeps-throwing-could-not-commit-submodules-error-and-i-dont-see-why-t/33729201#comment85848492_33729201):

> The new client [`desktop.github.com`](https://desktop.github.com/) doesn't have this problem anymore.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you :).

Comment: you saved my project

Comment: @t3chb0t Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because the mentioned folder was a [symlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows.

[image: src folder is symlink in windows]

[image: GitHub not allowing symlink to commit]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error for a different reason.

Being a novice programmer, I had used Github Desktop to accidentally create a repo within my repo.

[image: rookie mistake]

I just had to delete this folder.

Answer (score 0):

What worked simplest for me when I had the same issue was to just delete the duplicates of the .git files and .git folder.

The main project parent folder should have 2 files (.git and .gitignore) + a folder called .git (it may be a hidden folder)

I had these files duplicated in the next subfolder, which confused Github Desktop. So I just deleted all the duplicated instances of these files that were in the subfolder(s).