# how to copy folder without some inner folders (without the use of .dockerignore)?

Tags: docker

I have a the following docker file:

```
FROM my-reg:7678/py:v11
copy . /app/
# more commands...
```

I want to copy the content of `.` without 2 sub-folders: `.git` and `data`

I can't use `.dockerignore` because some docker files use the folder `data` and some are not.

(the docker files which use `data` folder use the `copy . /app/` command)

The solution here: [COPY with docker but with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747776/copy-with-docker-but-with-exclusion)
is not fit for me:
I want to let the docker file to decide to use or not `.dockerignore`. and It seems not efficient to copy the folder and after it to remove some sub folders.

- Is there a way to give `copy` command sub folders to ignore ?
- Is there a way to instruct the docker file to use `.dockerignore` file or to ignore it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COPY with docker but with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747776/copy-with-docker-but-with-exclusion)

Comment: no. as I wrote I want to ket the docker file to decide to use or not .dockerignore. and It seems not efficient to copy the folder and after it to remove some sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

About your questions:

Is there a way to give copy command sub folders to ignore ?

- I don't think there is another way to do this if you don't want to delete the copied folders.

Is there a way to instruct the docker file to use .dockerignore file or to ignore it ?

- See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774684/14388607), you can define multiple .dockerignore configs. So you could have one Dockerfile that does not ignore the data folder and one that does.