# How can I get around Docker's limitations on use of symlinks?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have multiple sets of files I want to include as data
for a web server.  Some of these sets are the static
assets to back a static website.

Suppose there are static assets for exactly two websites,
to be included as data for a web server.  Each set of assets
is laid out in its own folder, perhaps within a source code (e.g. git)
repository.  These are located at:

```
/path/to/site1/public
```

and

```
/other/path/to/site2/public
```

In fact there may be several sets of such static
assets located in different subdirectories of
folders in various places in the filesystem.

I need to install them into a Docker image as,
for example, `/var/www/http/site1`, and `/var/www/http/site2`,
and so on.

It would be very useful to have a good way to bypass
the Docker limitations on use of symlinks without
having to post these datasets on a web server somewhere
and refer to their URLs in Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is flexible and has worked well for me.
The current directory in this example is the parent
of the one containing the static assets, which are
in a folder named "public".

In this folder a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build a Docker image "site1-assets" with the static files.
docker build -f - --tag=site1-assets . <<EOF
FROM scratch
COPY public ./
EOF
```

Do similarly for static assets for site2, etc..
It doesn't matter where each set of files is located,
as long as they are all on the same machine.

Then in any Dockerfile that need the assets, lines
like this:

```
FROM site1-assets as site1
COPY / /

FROM site2-assets as site2
COPY / /

# and so on.

# And now the step that uses the external files.
FROM alpine

# Some config lines here ...

# Copy in files in image "site1".
COPY from=site1 / /var/www/http/site1/
# Copy in files in image "site2".
COPY from=site2 / /var/www/http/site2/

# More config lines if needed.

CMD run-my-app args
```

If the external images change rarely, you might wish
to copy the files in near the beginning of the client
Dockerfile.  If they change frequently, it might be
better to put them near the end.  The idea would be
to take advantage of Docker's ability to cache
partial image for use in future builds.

The core idea is basically the same as the option
"share a base image" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382248/5022006,
but more flexible than the scenario described there.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks work just fine inside Docker containers. The limitation with putting symlinks in docker images and containers is that only the link is copied, not the files it points to. Also, inside of a container, the symlink is relative to files and directories inside the image/container filesystem. Therefore, to use symlinks inside of a container, you need to make them relative to a directory structure that will also exist inside of the container. E.g. if you have the following:

```
path1/projA/link-good -> ../projB/file
path1/projA/link-bad1 -> /host/path1/projB/file
path1/projA/link-bad2 -> ../../path2/projC/file
path1/projA/link-bad3 -> ../projD/file
path1/projB/file
path2/projC/file
path1/projD/file
```

And you include those in your Dockerfile with:

```
COPY path1/projA/ /image/projA/
COPY path1/projB/ /image/projB/
COPY path2/projC/ /image/projC/
```

only the `link-good` link will work. The other links have the following issues:

- `link-bad1` points to a path that only exists on the host, use a relative path instead.
- `link-bad2` points to a relative path that doesn't exist inside the image because you added directories as `/image/proj*`, so there is no `path2` inside the image filesystem.
- `link-bad3` points to a file that was never included in the image, the `COPY` command does not follow links.

Comment: I'm not trying to put symlinks inside the container, but to work around Docker's designed-in restriction on use of symlinks to the source data in COPY commands when _building_ a Docker image. I try to make this clear in the question.

Comment: @CrisP this answer is describing how there is no designed-in restriction on using symlinks when building an image with the COPY command as long as you treat them as symlinks, and not the content the symlink is pointing to. This is not a docker restriction, simply how symlinks behave when you package them with Linux utilities like tar.