# Copy all folders of the Dockerfile's parent directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a project structure as below

```
├───Project
│   ├───ServiceA
│   │    DockerFile
│   │    main.py
│   └───CommonFilesFolder
│        utils.py
```

and my DockerFile looks as below

```
FROM <base-image>

COPY . /app/
COPY ../CommonFilesFolder/ /app/CommonFilesFolder

ENV PYTHONPATH /app/

RUN pip install -U -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/

CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```

I understand that the line `COPY . /app/` will copy all the contents of ServiceA Folder (The folder in which the DockerFile exists) to the container's app folder.

Similarly, I also want to copy the folder CommonFilesFolder into the /app, so I tried the line

```
COPY ../CommonFilesFolder/ /app/CommonFilesFolder
```

which is throwing me the error during the build

> error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/CommonFilesFolder" not
> found: not found.
> Failed to build container

How exactly can I change the line `COPY ../CommonFilesFolder/ /app/CommonFilesFolder` to copy to the container.

Answer (score 1):

When building the container, you have to specify build context. I would say you use `docker build .`. That means your build context is current directory and you can't use anything outside of it.

Official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#description

Check this answer how to resolve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013639/12118546